# PHP Arrays - Merge two arrays where a value is added together

Tags: php, arrays

I need some more help regarding PHP Arrays and the issue I am having. I have an array like this: -

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      string(3) "100"
      ["id"]=>
      int(46)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      string(3) "300"
      ["id"]=>
      int(53)
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      string(3) "200"
      ["id"]=>
      int(46)
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like it to look more like this as array: -

```
array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      string(3) "300" <--- This has been added from Array 1 and 2
      ["id"]=>
      int(46)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
      ["count"]=>
      string(3) "300"
      ["id"]=>
      int(53)
    }
  }
```

Basically if the same id is in both areas I want the count number to be added to each other but if it's not then it needs to just be left alone and included in the array.

I have used a number of array functions such as array_merge and array_push but I am running out of ideas of how this could work. I have also started working on a foreach with if statements but I just got myself completely confused. I just need a second pair of eyes to look at the issue and see howe it can be done.

Thanks again everyone.

Comment: Would an array of this kind be useful? `array(array(["count"]=>300,["id"]=46),array(["count"]=>300,["id"]=53))`. This can be achieved with a custom function.

Comment: Hi moni_dragu, I'm not sure what your trying to say? That's what I'm trying to achieve from the two arrays.

Comment: Actually I was trying to propose a different array type, but got distracted. This is the type I was referring to: `array('id'=>'count')`, meaning in your sample `array('46'=>'300','53'=>'300')`

Comment: Actually that could be something to work with but I am still trying to find a way to merge them together and add the values.

Comment: This is however dumped out by two queries one for a live table and one for a archive table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work with something like this:

```
$idToCountArray = array(); //temporary array to store id => countSum
array_walk_recursive($inputArray, function($value,$key) { //walk each array in data structure
    if(isset(value['id']) && isset($value['count'])) {
        //we have found an entry with id and count:
        if(!isset($idToCountArray[$value['id']])) {
            //first count for id => create initial count
            $idToCountArray[$value['id']] = intval($value['count']);
        } else {
            //n'th count for id => add count to sum
            $idToCountArray[$value['id']] += intval($value['count']);
        }
    }
});
//build final structure:
$result = array();
foreach($idToCountArray as $id => $countSum) {
    $result[] = array('id' => $id, 'count' => ''.$countSum);
}
```

Please note that I have not testet the code and there is probably a more elegant/performant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
$end_array = array();

function build_end_array($item, $key){

    global $end_array;

    if (is_array($item)){

        if( isset($item["id"])){

            if(isset($end_array[$item["id"]]))
                $end_array[$item["id"]] = $end_array[$item["id"]] + $item["count"]*1;
            else 
                $end_array[$item["id"]] = $item["count"]*1;
        }
        else {
            array_walk($item, 'build_end_array');
        }
    }
}

array_walk($start_array, 'build_end_array');
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn%5Cn$start_array%20=%20array(%5Cn%200=%3Earray(%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct0=%3Earray(%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%22count%22=%3E%22100%22,%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%22id%22=%3E46%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct),%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct1=%3Earray(%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%22count%22=%3E%22300%22,%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%22id%22=%3E53%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct)%5Cn%20%5Ct%5Ct),%5Cn%201=%3Earray(%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct0=%3Earray(%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%20%22count%22=%3E%22200%22,%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%20%22id%22=%3E46%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct)%5Cn%5Ct%20)%5Cn);%5Cn%5Cn$end_array%20=%20array();%5Cn%5Cnfunction%20build_end_array($item,%20$key)%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Cn%5Ctglobal%20$end_array;%5Cn%5Ct%5Cn%5Ctif%20(is_array($item))%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctif(%20isset($item[%22id%22]))%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctif(isset($end_array[$item[%22id%22]]))%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct$end_array[$item[%22id%22]]%20%2B=%20$item[%22count%22]*1;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctelse%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct%5Ct$end_array[$item[%22id%22]]%20=%20$item[%22count%22]*1;%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%5Ctelse%20%7B%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%5Ctarray_walk($item,%20%27build_end_array%27);%5Cn%5Ct%5Ct%7D%5Cn%5Ct%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cnarray_walk($start_array,%20%27build_end_array%27);%5Cn%5Cnvar_dump($end_array);%5Cn%5Cn?%3E%5Cn).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ever so much everyone. I actually worked it by doing this: -

```
$fullArray = array_merge($live, $archive);

$array = array();
foreach($fullArray as $key=>$value) {
    $id = $value['id'];
    $array[$id][] = $value['count'];
}

$result = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $result[] = array('id' => $key, 'count' => array_sum($value));
}

return $result;
```